# batch file to delete files filename ending in particular characters

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am looking to write a batch file that will remove all files from a directory where there file name ends in a particular number.

Eg delete all files of type .js from a folder where the filename end in 1.1.1.0

Any tips as to how I may write such a batch file to achieve this?

How would it be different if I wanted to delete all of the files of type .js that didn't end in 1.1.1.0?

Comment: Or am I missing something? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, it seems you could just do:

```
del *1.1.1.0.js
```

Or, you could write a batch file (tmp.bat) like this:

```
del *%1.js
```

And call it:

```
tmp.bat 1.1.1.0
```

But that seems like overkill?

Is there something I'm missing?

Or, I guess you might want something like:

```
del %1\*%2.js
```

Which you would call as:

```
tmp.bat folderName 1.1.1.0
```

You may also want to pass a '/F' flag to delete, to make sure it deletes readonly files...

If you wanted to do files in subdirectories as well, the batch file could look like this:

```
echo del /f /s %1\*%2.js
```

Again, where %1 is the folder name to start from and %2 is the number you want to delete...

To do everything BUT a given number, you could do something like this:

```
attrib +h *%1.js
del /q *
attrib -h *%1.js
```

To delete everything BUT a given number, from a given folder you could do this:

```
pushd %1
attrib +h *%2.js
del /q *
attrib -h *%2.js
popd
```

Where %1 is the folder and %2 is the number

Comment: how could I modify the above to delete all files that DON'T end in 1.1.1.0.js ?

Comment: That's harder :0), because I don't think you can use wildcard deletes... Easy options may be to hide all of the files that DO end in 1.1.1.0.js, delete everything else, then unhide them...

Comment: Ok will try that - would it be possible to update your answer with an example of this please.

Comment: @amateur: How's that?  I've only done an example for the current folder, because I think it's going to get tricky doing it for subfolders...

Answer (score 0):

Just create a .bat file with the following:

```
del *1.1.1.0.js
```

and save it in your directory. Every time you run it, it will delete the files ending in 1.1.1.0.js

Comment: how could I modify the above to delete all files that DON'T end in 1.1.1.0.js ?