# Batch: Copy files where include and exclude conditions are met

Tags: batch-file, copy, iteration

My requirement is to write a batch script that will compare the files in two folders. If a file exists in both SourceFolder and TargetFolder, then overwrite the file in TargetFolder with the file in SourceFolder.

Using a for-statement and an if-statement I can achieve this:

```
for /R %Source% %%G in (Prefix.*.ext) do (
    if exist %Target%%%~nxG (
        del %%G
        copy %Target%%%~nxG %Source% 
    ) 
)
```

Although an additional requirement is to only copy files that start with 'prefix.' and end in '.ext' and also to exclude all files that contain the word 'exclude'.

In English: *Copy all files from that source folder that start with 'Prefix.', end in '.ext', does not contain the text 'exclude'. and already exists in the target folder.*

This is where I get stuck. Does anyone know how to do this in batch?

Comment: Have a look at my solution for this question.  I think you could probably adapt the same approach.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651406/copy-a-set-of-files-into-specific-directories-based-on-filename/7651629#7651629

Comment: @CareyGregory: I had a look at your answer for the other question and I don't see how it can help. It could potentially help if it was assumed that a file doesn't contain multiple '.'s.

Comment: I believe that Carey is answering your question. Essentially you need to loop with a `FOR` on the files to be included and check with an `IF` condition to filter out the files to be excluded. Maybe you should try it, and come back with a more detailed question on what does not work for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `xcopy` for this.  First, I am assuming that Prefix and ext are actual strings, to use variables instead you would have to wrap them like `%Prefix%`.

Second, you will have to make a new text file.  Name it `excludes.txt` and put it in the same directory as your batch file.  (If you don't want to make a batch file, then just put it in the directory that is active when you run the command).  The only contents of this file should be your EXCLUDE string with no quotes, or other markup.

Ok, the command itself:

```
xcopy %Source%\Prefix.*.ext %Target% /U /EXCLUDE:excludes.txt
```

To break it down:

1. `%Source%\Prefix.*.ext` Selects the files in the source folder that start with Prefix and end with .ext
2. `%Target%` Specifies the destination for the files
3. `/U` Only copy files that already exist in the target directory
4. `/EXCLUDE:excludes.txt` This will read in `excludes.txt` and exclude any file that matches any part of the `excludes.txt` file.

That's it!  This is probably easier than writing a FOR statement with a nested IF.

Comment: One other way to create the exclude file is to just do it inside the batch file:  
You can call `echo EXCLUDE > C:\excludes.txt` at the beginning of your file and then just use `/EXCLUDES:C:\excludes.txt`.  
That might be easier than creating the file ahead of time if you want to keep everything in on place.

Answer (score 0):

After reading [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881086/batch-file-to-delete-files-filename-ending-in-particular-characters), I ended up doing it like this. (Before the question got answered)

```
pushd %Target%
attrib +h *Exclude
for /R %%G in (Prefix.*.ext) do (
    if exist %Target%%%~nxG (
        del %%G
        copy %Target%%%~nxG 
    ) 
)
attrib -h *Exclude
popd
```

The xcopy solution probably looks better although I'd prefer not to have to create (and remove) files if I can help it.